# Existence of associated prime

Tags: commutative-algebra

For a Noetherian ring $R$, it is well known that $R$ has at least one associated prime. In particular, minimal primes of $R$ are associated primes. My questions is

> Question 1: For a commutative ring $R$ with 1 not necessarily Noetherian, is a minimal prime of $R$ an associated prime?

Maybe, more fundamental question is

> Question 2: Does a commutative ring with 1 have an associated prime?

I believe the answers are well known. A referece would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your definition of associated prime is $\mathfrak p=\operatorname{Ann}(x)$, then the answer is negative to both questions.

The ring $R=K[X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots]/(X_1^2,\dots,X_n^2,\dots)$ doesn't have any associated prime, and, of course, it has a minimal prime ideal.

However, $R$ has a [weakly associated prime](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0546).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does it have an "associated prime" under a different definition that is be equivalent if $R$ is Noetherian?

Comment: @Youngsu See [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0546).